# I'm a Physiotherapist graduated in Brazil and would like to move to France, How does it work for Brazilians to work as a physio in France?

Tags: france, brazil

As I mentioned in the question, I would like to move to France and work there as a Physiotherapist. I graduated in Physiotherapy back in Brazil and over there it is a five-year programme, and according to what I've read in the French National Council of Physiotherapists website, physiotherapy bachelors degree is a four year programme in France. So I guess it is great that in Brazil it is 5 years, because then it is more likely that the curriculum will be compatible.
Has anyone from Brazil moved to France with the same plans to work there as a Physio or know someone who's done it?

Comment: The easiest way would be to establish yourself as a citizen by descent of a European Union country, if you can do that (there seem to be a number of Brazilians with Italian roots, and of course Portugal is another likely possibility).  Otherwise I doubt that it's possible to get a work permit based solely on qualifications as a physiotherapist since, as far as I know, there isn't a shortage of physiotherapists in France.

Comment: This https://ec.europa.eu/immigration/index_en might be helpful, if you’ve not already read it

Comment: (+1) Physiotherapist (*masseur kinésithérapeute*) is a regulated health profession. Apart from the immigration angle, getting your qualifications recognised is not trivial (AFAIK, you have to register at a school, will get an exemption from some or most courses based on your Brazilian diploma but still should sit for exams to get a French diploma). That wouldn't be solved by holding EU citizenship or finding another immigration route. Hopefully someone will be able to provide more details.